Android change color of a character at cursor position when using editext selection handle
I want to change text color of the character at the cursor position of edittext. I am listening onSelectionChanged callback then setText with new spannable and setCursor again to the current position. But when i was using text selection handle in order to move cursor, it will be interrupted by setText and setSelection.
So do you know anyway can change text color at cursor position when using text selection handle?
Or how can i listen an event like after selectionChanged?
I tried to use onTouch and onGestureListener to listen up or cancel action, but it doesn't work all case. Because text selection handle can drag and move on whole screen. And I can't detect correctly what action I needed.
